# C Pointers - swap

Tags: c, pointers, casting, swap

I'm playing with pointers in C...
Instead of the regular swap that receives pointers to values and swaps values, I'm trying to write a swap that receives pointers to values, retrives pointers of the pointers and swap pointers to values.

Here's the code...

Swap function:

```
void swap(void *left, void *right)
{
puts("\nswap function:\n\n");

printf("&left :  %i   -   left:  %i   -   *left(should be a):  %i\n",
            &left, left, *((int *)left));
printf("&right : %i   -   right: %i   -   *right(should be b): %i\n\n",
            &right, right, *((int *)right));

void *PNT_left =  (void *) &left;
void *PNT_right = (void *) &right;

puts("Before swap:");
printf("PNT_left:  %i   -   left: %i\n", (int *)PNT_left, *((int *)PNT_left));
printf("PNT_right: %i   -   right: %i\n\n", (int *)PNT_right, *((int *)PNT_right));

/* swap pointers of pointers*/
void *tmpPNT = PNT_left;
PNT_left = PNT_right;
PNT_right = tmpPNT;

puts("Pointer of pointer swapped:");
printf("PNT_left:  %i   -   left: %i\n", (int *)PNT_left, *((int *)PNT_left));
printf("PNT_right: %i   -   right: %i\n\n", (int *)PNT_right, *((int *)PNT_right));

/* swap pointers*/
tmpPNT = (void *)right;
*((int *)PNT_left) = (int *)left;
*((int *)PNT_right) = (int *)tmpPNT;

puts("Pointer swapped:");
printf("PNT_left:  %i   -   left: %i\n", (int *)PNT_left, *((int *)PNT_left));
printf("PNT_right: %i   -   right: %i\n\n", (int *)PNT_right, *((int *)PNT_right));

puts("Info:");
printf("&left :  %i   -   left:  %i   -   *left:  %i\n",
    &left, left, *((int *)left));
printf("&right : %i   -   right: %i   -   *right: %i\n\n", 
    &right, right, *((int *)right));

puts("End Swap function.\n\n\n");
return;
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    puts("Before - Info:");
    printf(" a: %i   -    b: %i\n", a, b);
    printf("*a: %i   -   *b: %i\n\n", &a, &b);

    swap(&a, &b);

    puts("After - Info:");
    printf("*a: %i   -   *b: %i\n", &a, &b);
    printf(" a: %i   -    b: %i\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before - Info:
 a: 1   -    b: 2
*a: -346930776   -   *b: -346930772


Swap function:

&left :  -346930760   -   left:  -346930776   -   *left(should be a):  1
&right : -346930752   -   right: -346930772   -   *right(should be b): 2

Before swap:
PNT_left:  -346930760   -   left: -346930776
PNT_right: -346930752   -   right: -346930772

Pointer of pointer swapped:
PNT_left:  -346930752   -   left: -346930772
PNT_right: -346930760   -   right: -346930776

Pointer swapped:
PNT_left:  -346930752   -   left: -346930776
PNT_right: -346930760   -   right: -346930772

Info:
&left :  -346930760   -   left:  -346930772   -   *left:  2
&right : -346930752   -   right: -346930776   -   *right: 1

End Swap function.


*a: -346930776   -   *b: -346930772
 a: 1   -    b: 2
```

Why a and b haven't been swapped? I've tried it also in main, so it's not related to passing by ref or value.

And why if I try to print out *((int *) *((int *)PNT_left)) the program reached SEGMENTATION FAULT while print out *((int) left) works, since at the beginning *((int *)PNT_left)) = left?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Use specifier `%p` to print address .

Comment: Search for and read about *emulating passing by reference in c*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank u... however I've specified I've tried it also in the main function...

Answer (score 3):

In

```
void *PNT_left =  (void *) &left;
void *PNT_right = (void *) &right;
```

you take addresses of local variables as pointers are passed by value in C. You have to pass addresses of pointers if you want change the pointers in function and keep this change visible outside of the function.

[Here](https://ideone.com/GGEzaR) you can find your code corrected.

You should add this in line 33

```
/* swap values*/
int tmp = *((int*)(*left));
*((int *)(*left)) = *((int *)(*right));
*((int *)(*right)) = tmp;
```

should you wish to exchange data too.

Comment: The same code in the the main function produce the same results, except addresses of course...

Comment: @NicholasRoveda Please look carefully.

Comment: Ok, sorry. So Pointers of pointers swapped, but a and b value are the same... why?

Comment: Not only the pointers of pointers, but the pointers themselves. Because OP wanted to swap pointers only. It is easy to make this swapping also the data.

Comment: Ok, perfect... the last point: why if I try to print out *((int *) *((int *)PNT_left)) the program reached SEGMENTATION FAULT while print out *((int) left) works, since at the beginning *((int *)PNT_left)) = left?

Comment: @NicholasRoveda Please do not change the link I pasted but instead copy the code to new location and experiment with that version, otherwise mine links become out of sync with my posts. To answer your question: could you please show the code? I have added code to exchange the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change where a pointer points to inside of a function, you have to pass a pointer-of-a-pointer into the function. Otherwise the pointer gets copied and you only change the pointer *inside* the function.

Think of it like this: with a function `void myfunc(int a)`, `a` gets copied, you cannot change its value outside of the function from within. If you use a pointer `myfunc(int *a)`, you can change the value *outside* the function. Therefore, if you want to change the value of a pointer *outside*, you have to pass a pointer-of-a-pointer.

#### Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_ptr(int **a, int **b) {
    void *buffer = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    int *a_ptr = &a;
    int *b_ptr = &b;

    printf("%p %p\n",  a_ptr,  b_ptr);
    printf("%i %i\n", *a_ptr, *b_ptr);

    swap_ptr(&a_ptr, &b_ptr);
    printf("-- swap --\n");

    printf("%p %p\n",  a_ptr,  b_ptr);
    printf("%i %i\n", *a_ptr, *b_ptr);
}
```

#### Output:

```
0x7fff5c663b6c 0x7fff5c663b68
1 2
-- swap --
0x7fff5c663b68 0x7fff5c663b6c
2 1
```

Comment: Ok, I knew it, I'm not new in C, so I don't understand why the same code in the main function produced the same result, it didn't swap... and the fact *((int *)*((int)PNT_left/right)) doesn't work...

Comment: @NicholasRoveda: Your code *cannot* work because you only pass *ptr-to-int* to the function instead of *ptr-to-ptr-to-int*. Inside `swap` this works, but this *cannot* propagate to outside `swap`.